# How to use vec_env or SubProcVecEnv to run multiple gyms in parallel?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, openai-gym

I want to use multiple (OpenAI) gyms in parallel, to speed up my RL model. The way i see it, vec_env([github repo](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/common/vec_env/vec_env.py)) is the solution used at OpenAI to do exactly that. The documentation([OpenAI documentation for baselines](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/vec_envs.html)) feels semi-useful to me until now. Specifically i have a set of questions:

1. From the repo, i see that vec_env constructor is:

   def **init**(self, num_envs, observation_space, action_space):
   ...

This seems weird, should it not contain a specification, of which envs i am using?

2. Documentation kind of confuses me even more: Seems like as user i maybe should rather use SubProcVecEnv to get multiprocessing for envs? If yes, then constructor is not clear again:

   class stable_baselines.common.vec_env.SubprocVecEnv(env_fns, start_method=None)
   ...

env_fns is explained as: env_fns – ([Gym Environment]) Environments to run in subprocesses

Is this: A list of strings defining the respective environments, or a list of gyms (returns from gym.make(env_name)), or something else?

3. If SubProcVecEnv is the way to go, how is it used: The way i see it, i just use:

   step_async(actions)
   step_wait()

wherever i used

```
step(action)
```

before, just with having action of size (batch_size, action_size) instead of size (action_size).

Can someone confirm?

4. Where from to import? I know about them from the OpenAI baselines, which are not exactly a library one would typically use, it seems to be more of a learning-tool. Is there a more 'professional' thing, where one could import them from?